# Symfony3 phpunit xml

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

Hey All installed PhpUnit in my Symfony3 project and when I run in in my terminal bin/phpunit -c app i get this error:

```
Could not load XML from empty string
```

Googled it and it turned out I needed to app a phpunit.xml file in my app/ directory so I did and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
        backupGlobals               = "false"
        backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
        colors                      = "true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
        processIsolation            = "false"
        stopOnFailure               = "false"
        syntaxCheck                 = "false"
        bootstrap                   = "autoload.php" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <!--directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory-->
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <!--directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory-->
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

So now it works fine but questions that i cant find open answers to are:

1. Why does php unit need this file I can see the file shows phpunit where to look for tests but is this all?
2. I created this file manually is there a way to create it automaticly like with a terminal command.
3. As far I understand `<whitelist>` is where phpunit is allowed to 'look' ? and `<exlude>` its where phpunit is not allowed to 'look' ? and if so then why would this `<directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>` be in `<exlude>` if that where the test are.

Answer (score 6):

With the new symfony3 directory structure the PHPUnit configuration files is located in the root of the project, so you don't need any more to specify the `-c` params (configuration). So you can launch simply as follow:

```
>bin/phpunit
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

To your questions first:

1. It is a configuration file. It lets you customize PHPUnits behaviour. For a full explaination of the file look at [the docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#appendixes.configuration).
2. The default installation of Symfony contains a `phpunit.xml.dist` file in the root directory ([See the repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard)). `.dist` in this case means it is the standard suggested by Symfony and you can change it to your needs. You probably did the same thing with your `parameters.yml.dist` file. Simply copy it and name it `phpunit.xml` and adjust any parameter to your current environment. Make sure that you do not checking the `phpunit.xml` file into your VCS so environment specific changes don't interfere with other systems you run your code on.
3. The `<whitelist>` and `<exclude>` elements define files that should be [*considered* by PHPUnit or *ignored*](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files). Since you added this block inside the `<filter>` element it defines all files for which PHPUnit should generate code coverage. You exclude your test files from that because you expect them to run and are only interested in how your actual code behaves under test conditions.

As to why your tests won't run I am uncertain. Try the way I described in point 2 and run `phpunit` in your project directory. For me it worked perfectly out of the box.

Comment: thank you for very usefull info. It works now but i need to move and rename phpunit.xml.dist from ./ root directory to app directory any idea why?. Also should phpunit.xml shouldynt be commited to VCS only phpunit.xml.dist and when project is cloned composer update will install phpunit.xml based n phpunit.xml.dist?

Comment: Good to hear. Yes exactly only commit the `.dist`. For the auto-renaming you probably have to use a script. Look at the [Incenteev/ParameterHandler](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler). That is the bundle that is used for the Symfony2 `parameters.yml.dist` file.

Answer (score 0):

like @Matteo said, the Symfony3 directory structure has changed.

I found in my case, I only need to change to the Symfony3 root directory and run:

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist
```

A default config file of "phpunit.xml.dist" is automatically created in your Symfony3 directory structure, you can modify that one to your needs. I just verified that the above runs on my system.